# Android webview: The method setProgress(int) is undefined for the type new WebChromeClient(){}

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am trying to set up a loading circle to show up in my android web view app. I have made a ton of progress since I started. Right now I am getting an error with the line setProgress.

The error message is:

The method setProgress(int) is undefined for the type new WebChromeClient(){}

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{   
    //Configure the webview setup in the xml layout
    public WebView myWebView;


     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //Remove title bar as we already have it in the web app
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
            //Point to the content view defined in XML
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);


            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            //Yes, we want javascript, pls.

            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            //Make sure links in the webview is handled by the webview and not sent to a full browser
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            //And let the fun begin
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

            myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                 public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                  // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
                  // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
                  this.setProgress(progress * 100);

                 }});

        }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        myWebView.goBack();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do instead

```
MainActivity.this.setProgress(progress * 100);
```

or just

```
setProgress(progress * 100);
```

So that you refer explictly to the parent class instance. Doing just `this` when inside the `WebChromeClient` refers to the instance of *that* class, and so you get a compile time error.

Since you are working with WebView, see the documentation for more info about [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)s and everything else related (including clients).

Comment: Awesome!. I took away this and it works! Well kinda works. I get no errors. But I do not see any loading bar when using my web app.

Comment: Right, since this is contained in an Activity, you can take away `this` entirely, I just do `Activity.this` out of habit :) As for the progress not showing, check to see if `onProgressChanged()` is being called.

Comment: I added a toast in there, and it show up every time I click to go to a new page. So onProgressChanged() is being called.

Comment: @Mike I can't say much. Seems in the example given in the `WebView` docs they do `progress * 1000`. Also try taking out  `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE` for testing.

Comment: That worked, apparently you need a title for the progress bar to show... I am going to try and research a way to do it without it.